# Why does a recursive function fail when calling for an outside predicatewould make it succeed?

Tags: recursion, prolog

I'm writing an implimentation of the factorial function. But I'm not quite sure why my method fails:

```
factorial(0,1).
factorial(N,F) :-
    X is div(F,N),
    factorial(N-1,X).
```

I'm giving it the test case:

```
?- factorial(1,1).
true
```

But instead it gives me a division by 0 error. Why does this function not grab back to the definition of `factorial(0,1)` when it reaches this, and how can I ensure that it does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`N-1` is a term and not a number.

You want instead to define

```
factorial(N,F) :-
    X is div(F,N),
    N1 is N - 1,
    factorial(N1,X).
```

If you trace the execution of your original code you would see that immediately.

```
?- trace,factorial(1,1),notrace.
   Call: (8) factorial(1, 1) ? creep
   Call: (9) _G1063 is 1 div 1 ? creep
   Exit: (9) 1 is 1 div 1 ? creep
   Call: (9) factorial(1-1, 1) ? creep
   Call: (10) _G1069 is 1 div (1-1) ? creep
ERROR: div/2: Arithmetic: evaluation error: `zero_divisor'
```

The term `1-1` does not unify with `0`, so the interpreter falls on to the second clause.

With `N1 is N - 1` the trace looks as you would expect.

```
?- trace,factorial(1,1),notrace.
   Call: (8) factorial(1, 1) ? creep
   Call: (9) _G2133 is 1 div 1 ? creep
   Exit: (9) 1 is 1 div 1 ? creep
   Call: (9) _G2136 is 1+ -1 ? creep
   Exit: (9) 0 is 1+ -1 ? creep
   Call: (9) factorial(0, 1) ? creep
   Exit: (9) factorial(0, 1) ? creep
   Exit: (8) factorial(1, 1) ? creep
true .
```

To make the factorial fail for `factorial(0,3)` you could add a guard predicate like `N > 0` in the main clause.

```
factorial(N,F) :-
    N > 0,
    X is div(F,N),
    N1 is N - 1,
    factorial(N1,X).
```

### Some more improvements

This is a not very useful predicate as it requires both arguments to be bound and would fail if either is a variable. In Prolog notation its signature is `factorial(+N,+F)`.

A more useful predicate would have a signature `factorial(+N,?F)`. This can be accomplished with the following definition

```
factorial(0,1).
factorial(N,F):-
    N > 0,
    N1 is N -1, 
    factorial(N1,X),
    F is X * N.
```

However this definition is not tail recursive, and we are told that such definitions do not use the stack efficiently. We need to carry along a
partial result to get a tail recursive definition for `factorial(+N,?F)`.

```
factorial(N,F):-factorial(N,1,F).
factorial(0,F,F).
factorial(N,X,F):-
    N>0,
    N1 is N - 1,
    X1 is X * N,
    factorial(N1,X1,F).
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes a lot of sense. I am running in to a secondary problem now though, which is that I don't know how to ensure `factorial(0,X)` return false for any `X` not equal to 1.

Comment: You could add a guard predicate like `N > 0` in the main clause.

Comment: The `N > 0` should be a necessary condition in that predicate clause. I wouldn't consider it optional.

Comment: @MitchellFaas I completed the post going all the way to a "canonical" definition of the `factorial` predicate.